# iOS 17 Tab bar is covering custom UIPresentationController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In our app we have a custom bottom sheet (subclass of UIPresentationController). Would love to use UISheetPresentationController but unfortunately we have to support iOS 15. And UISheetPresentationController is lacking in functionality on iOS 15.

When building the app in Xcode 15, iOS 17 devices have the safe area  portion of our custom bottom sheet cut off (well, not really, cut off, its behind the tab bar).

This does not happen for iOS 16 and older devices built in Xcode 15.

iOS 17 devices running the production version of the app (built in Xcode 14) do not have this problem.

Upon further inspection of the view hierarchy, it appears as though the containerView of my `UIPresentationController` is being presented on top of whatever view controller called `present(viewContorller:animated:)` instead of being on top of the entire view hierarchy.

I have tried the following:

- bringing the containerView to the front
- manually setting the zPosition
- overriding the train collection so that the ui level is elevated

The only thing I have found that works is to present the bottom sheet from my UITabBarController instead of my current view controller:

```swift
let newVC = MyVCToPresent()
newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
newVC.transitioningDelegate = MyBottomSheetTransitionDelegate()
vc.tabBarController?.present() // alternatively, I can use the root view in the UIWindow
```

Has iOS 17 changed the way UIPresentationControllers work?

Comment: It would be helpful show how you were doing it before.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not code I can share publicly.

But the problem was `shouldPresentInFullscreen` was set to `false`. Seems that in iOS 17, if that is set to false, what happens is the `containerView`of a UIPresentationController takes the frame of the `presentingView` rather than the size of the whole window.

Makes me wonder if that property was broken before iOS 17, because in iOS 16 and under, that property didn't seem to have any noticeable impact.

Comment: Something definitely changed around `UIPresentationController. shouldPresentInFullscreen` on iOS 17. I have a custom modal presentation with this property set to `false` (because the presented view controller does not cover the whole screen), and it seems on iOS 17 this somehow breaks the modal presentation model, because I now have a view controller down the hierarchy that will do wonky stuff on `dismiss(animated:)`... (dismiss a distant parent instead of itself)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue was `shouldPresentInFullscreen` was false on my BottomSheetPresentationController.

Setting it to true fixed the issue on iOS 17.

Need to do some further testing in previous versions to make sure its not broken there now...

Comment: Yes, that was right for me too, thank you!